# How to customize DataTables TableTools print preview page

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

I'm using this great [jQuery Datatables](http://datatables.net) with TableTools extension and everything works just fine except for print thing.

I have a sidebar on my page so when I click "Print", the sidebar is included on the print view which not good so what I did is hide it when the click event on the "Print" button is triggered but I don't know how to restore the sidebar again

I can use `.show()` and `.hide()` but I just don't know where to catch the event where someone exit on the print view (pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> will make the print view off).

Below code is what I tried:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

//initialize datatables
$('#test_table').dataTable( {
    "dom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
    "tableTools": {
        "sSwfPath": "/../../../plugins/datatables/extensions/TableTools/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
    }
} );
    //when they click the custom button that has a class of 'test_print' then trigger the datatables table tools button with a class of 'DTTT_button_print'
    $(".test_print").click(function(){
        $(".sidebar-toggle").hide(); //hide the sidebar
        $(".DTTT_button_print").trigger("click"); //trigger the click event
    });

});
```

How to catch the event where print view is turned off (when pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> the print view will exit) so that I could show my sidebar back?

Comment: Can you have the print view open in a new window (with everything hidden that needs to be hidden) and keep the original page with the sidebars? This way you don't have to watch when the print view is closed since it doesn't affect the original page.

Answer (score 1):

TableTools extension adds a special class `DTTT_Print` ([reference](http://datatables.net/extensions/tabletools/buttons#print%20)) to the `<body>` element, see [this example](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/extensions/TableTools/examples/simple.html). To hide an element with class `sidebar-toggle` add the following rules to your CSS file.

```
body.DTTT_Print .sidebar-toggle { display: none !important; } 

@media print {
 .sidebar-toggle { display: none !important; } 
}
```

First rule will hide `.sidebar-toggle` in TableTools print preview mode. Second rule will ensure that `.sidebar-toggle` is hidden if the page is printed without using TableTools print preview mode.

You don't have to show/hide elements via JavaScript with `show()`/`hide()`, CSS rules will take care of that. Your JavaScript code could be changed as follows:

```
$(".test_print").click(function(){
    $(".DTTT_button_print").trigger("click"); //trigger the click event
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following two functions:

```
function CreateTableFromObject(tblObj) {
    objHeader = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(tblObj.buttons.exportData()))["header"];
    objRows = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(tblObj.buttons.exportData()))["body"];

    //Check If Action Exists in Table and remove it
    var index = objHeader.indexOf('Action');
    if (index > -1) {
        objHeader.splice(index, 1);
    }

    tblToPrint = "<table style='border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse;'><thead><tr>";
    $.each(objHeader, function (key, value) {
        tblToPrint += "<th style='border: 1px solid black;'>" + value + "</th>";
    });
    tblToPrint += "</tr></thead><tbody>";
    $.each(objRows, function (key, value) {
        tblToPrint += "<tr>";
        //If action exists then decrease target by 1
        if (index > -1) {
            target = value.length - 1;
        }else {
            target = value.length;
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < target; i++) {
            tblToPrint += "<td style='border: 1px solid black;'>" + value[i] + "</td>";
        }
        tblToPrint += "</tr>";
    });
    tblToPrint += "</tbody></table>";
    return tblToPrint;
}

function PrintWindowAddParts() {
        var tblObj = $("#YourTable").DataTable();
        var tblViewRMA = CreateTableFromObject(tblObj);
        var printContents = "<div class='dataTables_wrapper form-inline dt-bootstrap'>" + tblViewRMA + "</div>";
        var size = 'height=' + $(window).height() + 'px,width=' + $(window).width() + 'px';
        var mywindow = window.open('', 'PRINT', size);
        mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>' + "My Title" + '</title>');
        mywindow.document.write('</head><body >');
        mywindow.document.write('<h4>' + "My Title" + '</h4>');
        mywindow.document.write(printContents);
        mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');
        mywindow.document.close();
        mywindow.focus();
        mywindow.print();
        mywindow.close();
        return true;
}
```

Your Print function is ready.

Answer (score 0):

You can use media queries to set some CSS that will only apply to prints, for example:

```
@media print {
  .sidebar-toggle { display: none !important; } 
}
```

Comment: You used `.sidebar-toggle` right? As that seems to be your actual class for your sidebar.

Comment: Perhaps you can take a look at [this article](http://tjvantoll.com/2012/06/15/detecting-print-requests-with-javascript/) on how to listen to print events, it also uses media queries.

Comment: Also, you need to remove `$(".sidebar-toggle").hide();` as CSS will do all the hiding/showing for you.

Comment: i even tried setting up the background to red yet sadly, still not working

Comment: Where did you put the `@media print` CSS? You should put them at the end of all your other CSS styles.

Comment: Also, the change would only be visible in the print preview window.